# Git fails at rebasing in modified commits

Tags: git, version-control, gerrit, rebase

We use gerrit for code reviewing. When working with a larger issue, I sometimes send several commits to Gerrit that depend on each other. Here is one such situation, where a, b and c are commits that are awaiting code review in Gerrit:

```
c
|
b
|
a
|
origin/master
```

If I get a comment on a, I need to fix whatever issue the code reviewer found, and make new commits for a, b and c (Gerrit is never able to handle the conflicts that arise when the dependency for b changes). To fix this, I check out a new branch called cr_fix from where I'm working (let's say master), and do a git reset --hard HEAD^^ (or using the id for commit a) so I end up with this:

```
a
|
origin/master
```

I can now fix the reported issues in a, make a new commit and push it to Gerrit. I now go back to master and do

```
git rebase cr_fix
```

The intention is to replace the a commit in master with the a commit in cr_fix.

This strategy works for me, but it is plagued by git constantly registering merge conflicts - it doesn't seem to be able to solve the simplest things.

Most notably the first commit it handles in the final rebase command (a in cr_fix on top of a in master) conflicts practically everywhere a change was made in cr_fix.

I've learned by now that I can basically always start the rebase off with a git rebase --skip, but I'm nervous that I'll do this and lose a commit somewhere.

So is there some way I can modify my workflow so I won't have to deal with these constant conflicts when rebasing? Maybe some option I can use or set?

Answer (score 1):

Your problems stem from trying to rebase A on top of A' (using capital letters here for readability). What you really want to do is rebase B and C on top of A', creating B' and C'. The easiest way of doing this is to use an interactive rebase,

```
git rebase -i origin/master
```

and amend A into A', and Git will automatically put B and C on top. This can of course still cause conflicts, but if A' touches the exact same code as B or C that's inevitable.

If you insist on creating a new branch for fixing up A into A' that's fine too (although I think you're working unnecessarily hard) but you have to make sure you're not trying to apply A.

When you run

```
git rebase cr_fix
```

you're effectively saying "backtrace the current branch until you find a commit that's reachable from cr_fix and rebase those commits to cr_fix". Given the situation you're in,

```
       o----A----B----C
       ^  \
       |   ------------A'
       |               ^
  origin/master        |
                     cr_fix
```

you'll be rebasing A, B, and C on top of A'. To make sure you're only rebasing B and C, use `git rebase --onto`:

```
git rebase --onto A' A
```

This means "backtrack until you get to a commit reachable from A and rebase those commits onto A'".

Comment: I have experimented some with git rebase --onto, but I'm not sure I understood what it did and it was even worse than my usual technique. I'll give it another go next time. I think maybe I only used one argument or mixed up the arguments somehow.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the same conflict over and over, you ca use rerere (see official documentation on http://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/08/rerere.html)

I wouldn't recommend though, because you'll have to manually revert it if you make a mistake when solving the conflict.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly you are trying to rebase your original branch on you new change.

Personally I never use rebase together with Gerrit as it always creates merge conflicts. After the fixing of commit a your tree looks like this:

```
origin/master --- a'
              \---a--b--c
                        ^
                        |
                       cr_fix
```

Now doing a rebase of `cr_fix` on `a'` will very often create a conflict as `a` large part of the changes in a are also present in `a'`. You should just cherry-pick `b` and `c` and you should not have any conflicts and your tree should look like this:

```
origin/master --- a'--b'--c'
              \---a--b--c
                        ^
                        |
                       cr_fix
```

When using Gerrit it is best never to use `git pull` and `git rebase` due to the changing tree structure as a result of the code reviews that you would normally not see in other git repos.

---

@Magnus

I do not use rebase because:

1. I use TortoiseGit, maybe it has the option to `git rebase --onto`, but to be honest I didn't know you could do this anyway
2. When you rebase, the original is gone. If any conflicts arise from the rebase and you made a mistake fixing it you lost your original code. By using `cherry-pick` you will always be able to reference back to the original revision
3. As a relative git newby, I have to show total git newbies how to fix problems with out of date change sets etc. Using `rebase` is very sensitive and often leads to loss code. It's best to let them always use `cherry-pick`, after a failed `cherry-pick` you can always reset the `HEAD` and try again. If you mess up a rebase you have lost your original changeset. And yes, I know you can get it back if you know the `SHA1`, but you can save yourself the trouble by using `cherry-pick`

I hope you understand why I prefer and recommend to use `cherry-pick` over `rebase`.

Comment: Please elaborate on "Personally I never use rebase together with Gerrit as it always creates merge conflicts" and "When using Gerrit it is best never to use git pull and git rebase due to the changing tree structure as a result of the code reviews that you would normally not see in other git repos". I suspect you're either using Gerrit in a weird or non-optimal way or misunderstanding something.

Comment: While it's been a hassle, I have never lost code when doing git rebase. I use git rebase --abort when things start going wrong, and that has always worked.

Comment: I use cherry-pick sometimes as an alternative technique, but it would be nice to be able to rebase everything in one command.